# Question about reading proof notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, formal-proofs

When reading the following problem, do you assume that each premise is true? So since number 2 states ¬ B am I to assume that ¬ B is true? Which would mean B is false?

1. A ∨ C → D    Premise
2. ¬ B          Premise
3. A ∨ B        Premise
4. A            2, 3, Disjunctive Syllogism
5. A ∨ C        4, Addition
6. D            1, 5, Modus Ponens
   QED.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I fear there's a bit of information one needs to make this a legitimate proof: why do you suppose $A \lor B$? Perhaps with the proper motivation (i.e., context), we could help you understand the proof.

Comment: It seems likely that whomever listed these statements was identifying the first three items there as premises (assumptions).  If $¬ B$ is a premise, then you are assuming the logical negation of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can take premises as taken to be "true" (assumptions taken as given) from which you are to derive the conclusion.  So given the premise $\lnot B,$ any assertion $B$ would lead to a contradiction.

So in your example,  given $A\lor B$, and given $\lnot B$, we appeal to the rule of inference called disjunctive syllogism to warrant (justify) the deduction$A$.

From the deduced $A$, we use addition to "add" $A \lor C$ (since if A is logically deduced from accepted premises, and thus taken as true, so must $A\lor C$ be inferred.

Then, by modus ponens with the first premise and the inferred $A\lor C$, we conclude $\therefore D$.

Comment: Sweet, I think this makes more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

dictionary.com defines:

*'Premise': a statement which is assumed to be true for the purpose of an argument from which a conclusion is drawn*